# Regex : How can I match a path which starts with '$' and ends in a blank space?

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to match a path from a description with regex so that it only selects the path which starts with **'$'** has **'/'** and **Alphanumerics**. It ends in a **blank** or **\n**.
It might however might contain a blank space within the path, which should be matched.

Can anyone suggest me one?

My working Regex is : `\$[\/\w\s]+`
This is not being able to finish the match.

Trial run :

```
String = 
"Create a folder At Below Location 

Path:-$/LoremIpsum/Main/Source/Dolores 
Central/Libraries/Umbridge
Folder Name:-Umbridge"
```

Output:
    $/LoremIpsum/Main/Source/Dolores 
    Central/Libraries/Umbridge
    Folder Name

Required:
    $/LoremIpsum/Main/Source/Dolores Central/Libraries/Umbridge

Comment: Try `Regex.Match(s, @"(?sm)\$.*?(?=^Folder Name:)").Value.Replace("\r\n", "")`. Or, to post-process any CR and LF sequence, replace `.Replace("\r\n", "")` with `.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "")`. This will work if you need to get all string from `$` till `Folder Name` at the start of a line.

Comment: Ankit, any feedback?

Comment: Sorry my requirement was something else. It does not necessarily need to stop only before "Folder Name". It just had to be a whitespace at the end.
It should however accept whitespaces in the middle.
This solved my problem `\$[\w\W]+\/+\S+` as provided by @anshuman anand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this brother:

```
\$[\w\W]+\/+\S+
```

[**You can see the Demo of working regex here.**](https://pythex.org/?regex=(%5C%24%5B%5Cw%5CW%5D%2B%2F%2B%5CS%2B)&test_string=String%20%3D%20%0A%22Create%20a%20folder%20At%20Below%20Location%20%0A%0APath%3A-%24%2FLoremIpsum%2FMain%2FSource%2FDolores%20%0ACentral%2FLibraries%2FUmbridge%0AFolder%20Name%3A-Umbridge%22&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

i hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy. It worked. You missed to escape the front slash though. Correct one : `\$[\w\W]+\/+\S+` if some one refers this later on!

Answer (score 0):

You might match a repeating pattern that matches a forward slash followed by a whitespace character or a word character.

For the last part you could match a forward slash, zero or more times a word or a whitespace character followed by a single character and an optional whitespace character so it can end in a blank space or a newline.

[`\$(?:/[\w\s]+)*/[\w ]*\w\s?`](https://regex101.com/r/SkYIPQ/1)

**Explanation**

- `\$` Match `$`
- `(?:/` Non capturing group

  - `[\w\s]+` Match one or more times a whitespace character or a word character
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat zero or more times
- `/[\w ]*` Match a word character or a whitespace zero or more times
- `\w\s?` Match a word character and and optional whitespace character